# bash execute permissions fail

Tags: bash

This works

```
bash
ifconfig
```

This fails

```
bash ifconfig
/sbin/ifconfig: /sbin/ifconfig: cannot execute binary file
```

It's not /sbin, as I've tried copying ifconfig (or any other binary) to a different location e.g.

```
cp /sbin/ifconfig ~
bash ~/ifconfig
/root/ifconfig: /root/ifconfig: cannot execute binary file
```

I've tried printing 'id -a' and LD_LIBRARY_PATH in /etc/profile to debug and all looks identical.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? I don't see what this has to do with a "permissions fail"

Comment: We have an application that does similar to the above - I'm trying to debug why we can't execute commands via bash like this. ifconfig is just an example. We can't seem to execute any binary (via bash). Once in the shell, it's all fine. I'd just like to understand what could be different here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you type `bash ifconfig`, bash is interpreting "ifconfig" to be the name of a script file that you want bash to run.  Bash is complaining because it wasn't expecting ifconfig to be a binary.  The correct form would be `bash -c ifconfig`.